# parametric equation differentiation challenge

Tags: calculus

When $y(t)=t^m+t^{-m}$ and $x(t)=t+t^{-1}$, show that:
$$
(x^2-4)\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}+x\frac{dy(x)}{dx}-m^2y(x)=0
$$

I calculated the derivatives to be:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{mt^m-mt^{-m}}{t-t^{-1}}
$$
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=[\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}](\frac{dx}{dt})^{-2}
$$
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write the second derivative in terms of $t$

\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} & = \frac{d}{dt} \left[\frac{mt^m - mt^{-m}}{t - t^{-1}} \right] \frac{dt}{dx} \\
& = \frac{d}{dt} \left[\frac{mt^m - mt^{-m}}{t - t^{-1}}\right] \frac{1}{1 - t^{-2}}
\end{align*}

If you then substitute for $x = t + t^{-1}$, for $y$ and the derivatives in terms of $t$, you should be able to demonstrate that it becomes $0$.

Comment: It is there where I get stuck...

Comment: How should I proceed?

Comment: I agree it's a nasty problem but if the assertion is true, you should be able to prove it that way with relatively easy mathematical operations.